How to prevent default key subscription creation in APIM through products in terraform?
I am trying to create subscription through subscription snippet in Terraform but it is already creating it through product snippet. How can I stop that? I am using the below product snippet. I tried with keeping subscription_required = false & also tried by removing that line from the code itself but still it is creating subscription in the portal side.
# Product abcd
resource "azurerm_api_management_product" "product8" {
product_id            = var.product8_id
api_management_name   = var.api_management_name
resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
display_name          = var.product8_id
description           = "abcd"
subscription_required = false
approval_required     = false
published             = true

}

I want to create subscription through the below snippet.

resource "azurerm_api_management_subscription" "abcd" {
api_management_name = var.api_management_name
resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
user_id             = <provide user-id>
product_id          = <provide product-id>
display_name        = "ABCD"
allow_tracing       = false
state               = "active"
depends_on = [
azurerm_api_management_product.product8,
]
}

Can anyone help in this matter? To conclude, I want to stop the default subscription created by products.tf file and create it with subscription snippet
I am creating APIM infrastructure through terraform. I want to create subscriptions through subscription snippet but it is by default creating subscription through product snippet as well. I want to stop that. I tried by giving  subscription_required = false in the snippet but still it is creating. I removed that line from the code but still it is creating. So total 2 subscriptions are getting created. One with product snippet and other with subscription snippet. I want to stop that.
